# How to create user and group with specific id in directory389

Tags: linux, centos, openldap

Since I never worked with 389-ds, I am gonna ask probably stupid question.
How can I create group with gid=557, and create user which would have uid=135 that is associated with gid=557? For local is quite easy by using groupadd -g 557 group_name and useradd -u 135 -g 557 user_name... But for creating custom group with specific id and user with specific id, I really have no clue.

The general idea is to use same GID and UID for specific user from old NIS yellow pages db (as this service is planned to be decommissioned...

Answer (score 0):

After Google-ing around, there is a nice Java GUI called 389-console. fist we need to create group and ticking posix option and insert ID. Without this ds-389 would create automatic uidNumber and gidNumber starting from 1001. Similar case with user. After creating, posix checkbox option needs to be "ticked", and after that, we can set uidNumber and gidNumber...